# How to get Keys and values, while parsing Json using Scala-Play Json Framework?

Tags: json, scala, bigdata, jsonparser, play-json

I have a json file , which has some keys and values. I need to parse the Json and print the keys and their values. For example, the json file is like below. I want to print this as Keys and values

````
{
   "Parcer":[
      {
         "key":"0203",
         "value":{
                  "Encryption":
                               {
                                 "enabled":"yes",
                                 "encryption_type":"base64",
                                 "key":"334848484",
                                 "return":"name"
                                 }
                  }
      },
      {
         "key":"0405",
         "value":{
            "Encryption":
                        {
                           "enabled":"yes",
                           "encryption_type":"base64",
                           "key":"334848484",
                           "return":"none"
                        },
            "Parcer":[
                        {
                           "key":"0102",
                           "value":"humidity"
                        },
                        {
                           "key":"0304",
                           "value":{
                                    "Encryption":{
                                                   "enabled":"yes",
                                                   "encryption_type":"SHA1",
                                                   "key":"1211212",
                                                       "return":"none"
                                                }
                                        }
                            }
                         ]

                }
          }],
  }```
````

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to create a `case class`, like:

```
case class MyObj(header:String, value: Seq[Map[String, String]])
```

Then you just need to add one line for marshalling, like:

```
import play.api.libs.json._

object MyObj {
  implicit val jsonFormat: OFormat[MyObj] = Json.format[MyObj]
}
```

Now you get a nice `case class` that you can work with:

```
  val json =
    Json.parse(
      """{
   "header" : "header value",
   "value" : [
        {
         "a" : "a_val",
         "b" : "b_val",
         "c" : "c_val"
        },
        {
        "a" : "a_val",
         "b" : "b_val",
         "c" : "c_val"
        }
     ]
}""")
```

Here an example how to retrieve all `"a"`.

```
  json.validate[MyObj] match {
    case JsSuccess(myObj, _) =>

      val allAs =myObj.value.flatMap(m => m.get("a").toSeq)
      println(allAs) // >> Vector(a_val, a_val)
    case e:JsError => // handle error
  }
```

This gives you:

`json.validate[MyObj]` returns `JsSuccess(MyObj(header value,Vector(Map(a -> a_val, b -> b_val, c -> c_val), Map(a -> a_val, b -> b_val, c -> c_val))),)`

The `println` returns: `Vector(a_val, a_val)`

This is described here in the Documentation: [JSON automated mapping](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJsonAutomated#JSON-automated-mapping)

Comment: If the values inside `value` are not always String (_what a horrible sentence..._), the Map could be changed to `value: Seq[Map[String, Any]]`. Might be a consideration :-)

Comment: How we handle the nested values in "a"?

Comment: Instead of "a" can we specify the JsPath ?

Comment: then you don't need to translate it first to a `case class` - but I can't help you there because I always use the way i showed you in my answer

Comment: Edited my question and checked your answer with this json. But it didnt work. I am new to scala. Sorry for the mistakes.

Comment: this is a way more complex structure - then in your initial question

Comment: the best you can do -is revert your change - then check if my solution works for it - if so accept it and ask another question with a more accurate example (like edited version) - otherwise I have to remove my answer;(

Comment: I've been looking for a way to do something like this, and many of the other SO questions on the front page of Google claim that Play has no native Reads for Maps.  They are, admittedly, older.  Can we add a link to the documentation and/or change notes that add this functionality?

Comment: @Mystagogue - I adjusted my answer - thanks for the hint

Comment: @pme I'm not sure the link you added actually contains the relevant information.  There's no indication that Play handles `Map` natively on that page.  Looking through the source code, they actually have a special case for handling Maps, which I would expect to be documented somewhere.